# Is Steam Link more demanding on your PC?

Tags: steam, pc

I am thinking about buying a steam link. If I stream a game from my PC to TV using it, will my PC have to do much more work? I heard that it still displays the game on your monitor as well as the TV. Will that cause my PC to do a lot more work?

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but here's my input: I've not really noticed a performance drop in general, **except** in Duck Game, where I noticed I would drop frames occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The impact depends on a few things:

- PC
- home network
- TV

In general you shouldn't feel a difference, unless one or more of the components bottlenecks the connection (Slow TV or network, old PC, ...). Also like mentioned in the comment some games may cause problems (e.g. vsync is disabled while streaming), but that's pretty much unpredictable.

The PC itself will not feel much of an extra impact, unless you have a bad graphics card or an old PC altogether. **Yes, it will have some extra work**, if the game is displayed on both your monitor and TV as the GPU will have some extra load. Anyway, since the game is only rendered once and then duplicated the impact should still be low enough to not or hardly feel it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, in order to run the Steam Link ... you PC must be connected to the same network, and running in Steam "Big Picture" mode.

Secondly, yes, essentially any game you are playing is streaming between your computer and the Steam Link. Unless your wireless is *very fast*, you should likely have a wired connection... it seems to work well-enough with a 100MB switch as "a bottleneck" (I have full Gig-E as my backbone, but one of the in-between switches on that network segment is only a 100MB switch ... and it works pretty well, even for something like Rocket League).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The OP asked if streaming the games from their PC to the steam link would require more effort from their PC

Comment: The obvious answer, here, is "yes" ... essentially, you are playing the game on your PC *and* streaming it to the Steam Link.